# IF in MySql request

Tags: mysql, if-statement

**In MySql language** , I don't know if we can make a code like this ( it's just a example ) :

```
If ( "my Query select" is empty ) { "another query select" }
else {"my Query select"}
```

I find some examples on internet, but it's not work and i don't understand.

Thank for all

Comment: please read some database books..

Comment: Conditional *statements* can only be used within blocks `BEGIN - END`. Conditional *expressions* can be used either of `CASE - END` and `IF` within *a statement*.

Comment: of course it's can be done you just need to google a little and you will find a lot of examples... for example start [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/) ... i find it in 5 second. I just typed in google 'MySql IF Statement'... try that you'll be surprised how easy it is...

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
(
  CASE
   WHEN ... THEN
   ELSE ... 
  END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax:-

```
SELECT IF((YOUR SELECT QUERY) IS NULL, (ANOTHER SELECT QUERY),
(YOUR SELECT QUERY));
```